# SQL Query joining parent table with several children rows into one row

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to implement query to take setups information from database where one setup has link to several items types: Controller, platform and KVM device.

This way:

```
         Rack 
           |
          Setup 
  /        |         \
controller Platform   KVM
```

Connections between parent and children are stored in another table.

I tried the bellow query, but I got setup children in separated rows. 
How can I improve query to solve this?

Query:

```
 select R.Id as Rack_Id, 
 S.Id,C.Id as Setup_Id, 
 P.Id as Platform_Id, 
 K.Id as KVM_Id, 
 R.Capacity, R.[Rack location],
 S.[Location in Rack], C.[Controller IP], P.ISMP, P.Platform
 From #Racks R join LinksAre LR on LR.SourceId = R.Id
 join #Setups S on LR.TargetId=S.Id
 left join LinksAre LS on LS.SourceId = S.Id
 left join #KVMs K on LS.TargetID = K.Id
 left join #Controllers C on LS.TargetId=C.Id
 left join #Platforms P on LS.TargetId = P.Id
 order by R.Id, S.Id
```

Thanks!

Comment: use `inner join` instead of `left join` and feedback me, thanks.

Comment: I need left join to include setups without controller

Answer (score 0):

Think you might need a subquery:

```
select R.Id as Rack_Id, 
       S.Id,C.Id as Setup_Id, 
       P.Id as Platform_Id, 
       K.Id as KVM_Id, 
       R.Capacity, R.[Rack location],
       ( SELECT S.[Location in Rack] FROM #Setups S
         WHERE S.ID = LR.TargetId) AS ColumnA,         
       C.[Controller IP], 
       P.ISMP, P.Platform
  From #Racks R join LinksAre LR on LR.SourceId = R.Id
    left join LinksAre LS on LS.SourceId = S.Id
    left join #KVMs K on LS.TargetID = K.Id
    left join #Controllers C on LS.TargetId=C.Id
    left join #Platforms P on LS.TargetId = P.Id
 order by R.Id, S.Id
```